# Next.js 301: How to redirect from source with query to destination without query

Tags: redirect, next.js

I would really appreciate if somebody helps me with this:

1. I have a source URL like `https://example.com/category/results/refine?dealers=123&inv=true&sellertypes=dealer`
2. I want to implement an SSR permanent 301 redirect to destination URL like `https://example.com/` if the source URL contains `dealers` and `inv` keys.
3. I've implemented the following code in my `next.config.ts`:

```js
async redirects() {
    return [
      {
        source: "/category/results/refine",
        has: [
          {
            type: "query",
            key: "dealers",
          },
          {
            type: "query",
            key: "inv",
            value: "true",
          },
        ],
        destination: "/",
        permanent: true,
        statusCode: 301,
      },
}
```

4. As a result I've got the redirect not to `https://example.com/` but to `https://example.com/?dealers=123&inv=true&sellertypes=dealer`. I mean, the query from source URL sticks to destination URL. And this is not what I expect.

Answer (score 2):

It does not look like this can be achieved via `nextjs` config - The documentation states:

> When a redirect is applied, any query values provided in the request will be passed through to the redirect destination. For example, see the following redirect configuration:
> When /old-blog/post-1?hello=world is requested, the client will be redirected to /blog/post-1?hello=world.

You have two options.

1. Implement a [custom server](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server), then do path matching and code which removes the query params
2. Implement a proxy like nginx or a CDN giving you fine grain control of routing.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved, but the solution is not obvious and ugly.

As @ramakay stated, every query parameter will be passed to the destination URL. If you do not want a parameter to be passed, you have to do the following thing:

1. Repeat the parameter itself in the destination URL
2. But without any value
3. Vercel will remove the parameter completely

So in your case this would look like this:

```
{
  source: "/category/results/refine",
  has: [
    {
      type: "query",
      key: "dealers",
    },
    {
      type: "query",
      key: "inv",
      value: "true",
    },
  ],
  destination: "/?dealers=&inv=",
  permanent: true,
  statusCode: 301,
},
```