# nextjs config redirect adding extra query param after redirection

Tags: reactjs, redirect, next.js

here is my config file redirect code

```js
async redirects() {
return [
{
 source: '/img-generator',
 has: [
  {
    type: 'query',
    key: 'vector_art',
    value: '(?<id>.*)',
  },
 ],
destination: '/img-generator/vector_art?/:id',
permanent: true,
},
]
}
```

and suppose if I am landing on this page:

http://localhost:3000/img-generator?vector_art=1234

I have been redirecting to this page as per redirect configuration
http://localhost:3000/img-generator/vector_art/1234?vector_art=1234
but is adds extra query param, don't know why this is happening!

pls help

Comment: I think this link can be the best solution for your problem [Nextjs Redirect Query Matching](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71844346/14882236)